# Can humans be printed?

Tags: human-biology, stem-cells

Is it possible to spray stem cells on fully grown skeleton to get fully grown humans?

Currently, just read about recent advances, and wondered if something like this is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

Very early in the development of an organism, it is just a clump of cells.  Then those cells communicate, and determine where they are in the clump, which determines their eventual fate in the full organism.  In mammals, for instance, cells split into three different layers, and the skin and nerve cells develop from cells in the outermost layer...etc.

You can't just dump a bunch of stem cells somewhere and expect them to know where they are and what they should be developing into.

Comment: I am tempted to downvote such a strong opinion... what if you replicated the exact configuration of elementary particles of a person?

Answer (score 2):

A skeleton is itself very complicated.  It's not just apatite in the shape of a skeleton.  The bones have structure, and many have bone marrow.  Tiny cells navigate through the bone matrix, keeping it sound.  Those cells, and the ones in the marrow, need a blood supply to keep them alive.  Plus, what swbarnes2 said.

Comment: And through these cells our bones are actually alive. The osteoclasts and osteoblasts are in a constant process of building up and breaking down bone mass.

Answer (score 0):

See spryaing stem cells is not that easy as it sounds.The main difficulty working with stem cell is keeping their stem cell characteristics intact till the development actually begins.Stem cell can be amny types such as pluripotent,totipotent,multipotent etc.As you asked bone,bone is also a result of stemcell.So point is first you have to generate bone and bone generation is a massive and intricate process.You need many growth factors for this process and these growth factors are developmental time specific it means it is expressed at only a certain point of time.So I think it's difficult